# Run onload event in the body tag of HTML before the window focus event

Tags: javascript

I want to call an onload event before an focus event in a HTML page.
In my following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body onload='onloading()'>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).focus(function(){

        callMe();
    });
});

function callMe()
{
    alert('Focus is on current page');
}

function onloading()
{
    alert('Onload function call ');
}
function myFunction() 
{
  document.write("some text");
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(); 
</script>
</head>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute this code then i get an a pop up as "Focus on current page " and in the back ground " some text" . But I expect to get an output in the following order

1. "some text"" in the back ground
2. "Onload function call"  popup
3. "Focus is on current page" pop up .

But I am not getting the pop up "Onload function call"  :( . I need to run the onload event in the body before the focus event. IS it possible to do such a thing ?

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: I have a an onload function "overloading()" that I want to call after full HTML page is loaded . Also when the HTML page is in focus/ running on foreground/tab is seen by the user then I want to run callMe() function . But the callMe() function needs to be called after the "overloading()" function is called

Comment: so on doc ready call you `overloading function and at the end of overloading call callMe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="focus">Click here</p>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
function callMe()
{
    $("#focus").html('Focus is on current page');
}

function onloading()
{
    alert('Onload function call ');
}
function myFunction() 
{
 $("#demo").html("some text");
}
$(window).load(function () {
 onloading();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#demo").html= myFunction(); 
    $(window).focus(function(){
       callMe();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it . You saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. You have put the `head` tag inside the `body` which is not allowed.

Make use of the following structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: who said this to you?

Comment: Even if your browser would handle this properly, it still isn't a valid reason to abuse it. The head tag is not allowed inside the body tag and vice versa.
I have noticed that your HTML tags are imbalanced. Please fix that first.

Comment: @com2ghz ps:close the HTML tag